# libuvc launch get permission denied opening usb error

Tags: camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, new bee to ROS,
I am following [libucv](http://wiki.ros.org/action/fullsearch/libuvc_camera?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=linkto%3A%22libuvc_camera%22), trying to run my webcam and publish to /camera/image_raw topic. Catkin_make is ok. but when I launch. I got permission denied opening errors like:

```
PARAMETERS
 * /camera/mycam/auto_exposure: 3
 * /camera/mycam/auto_white_balance: False
 * /camera/mycam/camera_info_url: file:///tmp/cam.yaml
 * /camera/mycam/frame_rate: 15
 * /camera/mycam/height: 480
 * /camera/mycam/index: 1
 * /camera/mycam/product: 0x0
 * /camera/mycam/serial: 
 * /camera/mycam/timestamp_method: start
 * /camera/mycam/vendor: 0x0
 * /camera/mycam/video_mode: uncompressed
 * /camera/mycam/width: 640
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.13

NODES
  /camera/
    mycam (libuvc_camera/camera_node)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[camera/mycam-1]: started with pid [12166]
**[ERROR] [1445862646.193876279]: Permission denied opening /dev/bus/usb/001/002**
[camera/mycam-1] process has died [pid 12166, exit code 255, cmd /home/visioner/libuvc_ws/devel/lib/libuvc_camera/camera_node __name:=mycam __log:=/home/visioner/.ros/log/f0455380-7b93-11e5-a62a-e4f89ca8e3f5/camera-mycam-1.log].
log file: /home/visioner/.ros/log/f0455380-7b93-11e5-a62a-e4f89ca8e3f5/camera-mycam-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
```

any ideas about this?
I am pretty sure my cameras are OK, I could find in `ls /dev/video*` , I even write a simple opencv program showing that I can get my camera run.

Any ideas about this? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219886/libuvc-launch-get-permission-denied-opening-usb-error/) by [flankechen](https://answers.ros.org/users/24891/flankechen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-10-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-10-26**:
What permissions does `ls -l /dev/video*` show?

**Comment by [flankechen](https://answers.ros.org/users/24891/flankechen/) on 2015-10-27**:
@joq, the permission is: crwxrwxrwx+

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-10-27**:
How about `/dev/bus/usb/001/*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Unless you're logged in a root then you will not have permission to write to the /dev/bus/usb/001/002 device.

I've just worked around this and it's a bit messy and you have to do it every time you connect the camera. Change your path to /dev/bus/usb/001/ and type "sudo chown  002"

This will give your user the permissions to access this device.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2015-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0